# @string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior is marked as private in com.android.support:design

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-coordinatorlayout, android-design-library

I have updated the support library to 28.0.0-alpha3, and lint gives me this warning `@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior is marked as private in com.android.support:design` while I am using this in layouts which have coordinator layout. What is the correct way to use this behaviour now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has been fixed but has not been released yet :

https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/commit/e1c8886c6c91fe277622a583cbba75bfc9c37f55

**UPDATE**

This has been fixed in version 28.0.0-rc01

Answer (score 1):

You may go to appbar_scrolling_view_behavior class and change **private** to **public** . But would be better if you use 27.1.1 version. Since offical documentation says **support library 28 is subject to change**[support library 28 is subject to change](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions)

Comment: There are some flinging issues with appbarlayout  which are fixed in 28 version only. So its kind of necessary to use that.